# How to send both command line arguments and standard inputs to a program from a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I'm trying to write a shell script which executes a C++ program. The C++ program takes both command line arguments and inputs from user. The program has different modes chosen by command line arguments. After selecting the mode, the program does a task, takes input from the user, and does another task. My aim is to send a bunch of pre-determined values to this program from shell script automatically.

If only command line arguments existed in the C++ program, the code would be:

```
 #! /bin/bash
./myprogram arg1 arg2 
do something here
```

If the C++ program required only standard input from users, the code would be:

```
 #! /bin/bash
./myprogram
do something here
echo "some input" | ./myprogram
do something
```

But I am having trouble combining these pieces of information. I shouldn't change the main cpp program. Therefore, I cannot remove command line arguments from my main program.

Finally, my code should seem like this:

```
#! /bin/bash
./myprogram arg1 arg2
do something here
echo "some input" | ./myprogram
do something
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try `echo "some input" | ./myprogram arg1 arg2` ? Or please explain why that is not applicable.

Comment: Your "If the C++ program takes only standard inputs..." example actually runs the program twice, once without providing input, and once with input.

Comment: Could you make your examples consistent? In the first, there is only one "do something" line, but in the second and third, there are two. That alone should tell you that there is an inconsistency to resolve before asking for help.

Comment: Inputs from the user are not necessarily "standard input". If you're trying to automate providing input to a program that prompts for it, take a look at `expect` and see if it will do what you need. Otherwise, please define your need more thoroughly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your situation correctly, it seems to be saying that you would like to use both command line parameters while also being able to pipe input into the same program as if typed from the standard input.

If so, then the solution is simple. You can do both at the same time:

```
echo "some input" | ./myprogram arg1 arg2
```

Parameters for a program are handled separately from STDIN. Therefore, there's no conflict. The C++ program would handle the parameters as an array passed into `main()`, and it would handle the input piped to it through a stream coming from STDIN.

It is up to the program itself to determine when and how it process that information. It is entirely possible that it could check first for STDIN. If it is the case that you need to delay your piped input, you might consider using the [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) command. Fortunately, it is common convention to handle the command line parameters first before moving on to do other things, such as checking for input, so the above should work in most cases.

Answer (score 0):

Asuming your bash script is script.sh

```
#! /bin/bash
#script.sh
argument1=$1
argument2=$2
echo $argument1
echo $argument2
./myprogram $argument1 $argument2
```

you can run it as

```
#./script.sh argument1 argument2
```